# What does Windows Backup do with symlinks?

Tags: windows-7, backup, symbolic-link

I'd like to use Windows Backup to backup my Documents folder, but I have very large datasets which I have several symlinks to in my Documents folder. These datasets are backed up elsewhere, so I don't want to include them in my backup. However, I also don't want to manually select all the subfolders of Documents that I *do* want to back up.

In the Help file, it states that Windows excludes the following from backups automatically:

1. Program files
2. Temporary files
3. Files in the recycle bin
4. Files formatted in the FAT file system

My questions are:

Will Windows Backup backup my symlinks automatically or exclude them?

Is there an easier way than manual folder selection to exclude them if Windows Backup doesn't already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimentally, it seems as if Windows Backup automatically excludes symlinks.

I made a symlink called "Visualizations" in my directory "C:/wamp/www"

[Folder containing symlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPBAR.png)

Then I opened the Windows Backup configuration tool and selected the "Let me choose" directories to backup setting. When I navigated to "C:/wamp/www" the "Visualizations" symlink was not shown.

[Windows Backup configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpBif.png)

I then ran the backup to see what happened. Again, when browsing the backup, the "Visualizations" symlink did not appear.

**Conclusion: Windows Backup does not backup symlinks.**

I would still be interested if anyone could find official documentation about this.

Comment: [Backup Browser screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2IR7N.png). I'm not allowed to include more than 3 links, based on my reputation.

Answer (score 0):

solution for this problem is:

fsutil behavior set SymlinkEvaluation L2L:1 R2R:1 L2R:1 R2L:1
fsutil behavior query SymlinkEvaluation

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788058(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: second command (fsutil behavior) is to check if following symbolic link feature is enabled

Comment: Please clarify and add a little more context to this answer to convey what you are suggesting exactly.